# How to get percentage of time that CPU usage is higher than x%?

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

I have this as a query to get CPU usage in percentage:

```
avg without (mode,cpu) (
  1 - rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle", job="openwrt"}[1m])
) *100
```

I want to get the percentage of time that the CPU usage is above, for example, 80%.

So for example if the data is `56.4 32.5 53.5 89.0 67.9 21.2 90.4 25.7 6.7 92.3` it'll be 3/10 = 30%

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
avg_over_time((
  avg without (mode,cpu) (
    1 - rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle", job="openwrt"}[1m])
  ) * 100 >bool 80
)[1h:1m]) * 100
```

This query returns the percentage of time when CPU sage was higher than 80% during the last hour. It uses [subquery feature](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) for calculating [avg_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg_over_time) over the per-minute average CPU usage for the last hour.